# What is a good tool for code/text generation?

Tags: code-generation, templating

I used to use a web based tool that took in a list of data, you supplied a template using placeholders for the individual fields in your data, and it generated output using your data and template. Anyone know of a tool like this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are exactly looking for, but you might want to take a look at [Yellicode](https://www.yellicode.com). It is not web based but still very lightweight and template-driven. It is based on npm and you build templates using Javascript/TypeScript, using any JSON file as input.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Telosys (http://www.telosys.org/). 
It’s a code generator working with templates using placeholders (see http://www.telosys.org/templates.html for more information about templates).

The templating engine is based on Velocity ( https://velocity.apache.org/ )

This tool has been designed to apply templates on “entities” (“entities definitions” are the “data” for the templates), but if you don’t need entities you can just use a set of “project variables”.